# Why is this throwing a java.util.InputMismatchException?

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
    public static void readFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        scan.useDelimiter("/|\\.");
        scan.nextLine();

        GrocerieList.foodList.add(scan.next());
        GrocerieList.foodAmount.add(scan.nextInt());

        System.out.println(GrocerieList.foodList);  // this is for testing
        System.out.println(GrocerieList.foodAmount); // also for testing
    }
```

This is the code for foodAmount:

```
static ArrayList<Integer> foodAmount = new ArrayList<>();
```

The file that holds holds my input is a simple .txt and the input looks like this:

```
eggs
bread.
3
6.
```

Now there shouldn't be a mismatch in my mind because `GrocerieList.foodAmount.add(scan.nextInt());` clearly picks up two integers?!

Comment: But `scan.nextInt()` is trying to read *an* integer value.  If it sees two, what single number is it supposed to return?

Comment: I had that thought too - but the same exception gets thrown if the .txt has only one integer value before the delimiter

Comment: foodList is an ArrayList of String?

Comment: yes, foodList is an ArrayList of String!

Answer (score 0):

```
scan.useDelimiter("[/|\\.\n]");
```

fixes it.
if you also add a `scan.nextLine()` after adding to the foodList to consume the period.
See [Scanner delimiter not working as expectedwith input file (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978417/scanner-delimiter-not-working-as-expectedwith-input-file-java)

That fixes the error. It remains true that you are currently reading and storing only bread and only reading the 3 and not the 6.